# How to parse all the game data from the steam website from first page? i am using python

Tags: python

i am trying to parse all the game title from the first page from the steam website but this code bring only first game title how i can deal with it

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = f'https://store.steampowered.com/category/sports_and_racing/#p=0&tab=NewReleases'

r = requests.get(url, headers=h)

content = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')


all_games_block = soup.find('div', 'class', class_='tab_content_ctn sub')

all_games = all_games_block.find_all('div', id='NewReleasesRows')

for each in all_games:

title = each.a.find('div', class_='tab_item_name').text

print(f'title:{title}')
```